# Angular 4 - How to make bulk http syncronous requests

Tags: angular, observable, synchronous, bulk

I have in my Angular 4 App a formulary to upload data. This data comes in a array of JSON elements and I loop over it to make an HTTP PUT request through an observable.

If a little set of elements are going to be upload everything works fine, but sometimes input can be 1000+ elements large.

As I'm using observables, all the request are made in a synchronous way, so at the same time. That makes the backend literally crash if the number of elements is big enough.

I need to make the HTTP requests one by one but I don't know how to do it. ¿Could you help me?

Service function:

```
putIp(ip, data): any {
const url = `${this.IpUrl}/${ip}`;
return this.authHttp.put(url, data, {headers: this.headers});}
```

Component function:

```
       publishIps(): void {
     console.log("Publishing Ips")

     for (let _i = 0; _i < this.ipsInTable.length; _i++) {
         this.ipsInTable[_i].treated = true;
         this.ipService.putIp(this.ipsInTable[_i].id, this.ipsInTable[_i].json)
         .catch(err => {
           this.ipsInTable[_i].result = false;
           this.ipsInTable[_i].message = "Error";
           return Observable.throw(this.errorHandler(err));
         })
         .subscribe((data) => {
            // Doing some stuff
         });
     }
   }
```

Comment: if you want to do it one by one , why not use a promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would tweak the backend to accept an array of objects.  Then you just do one request.

If that's not an option, and you want to submit the request one at a time, here's a different approach to your controller code:

```
publishIp(_i: int): void {
   if (_i < this.ipsInTable.length) {

     this.ipsInTable[_i].treated = true;
     this.ipService.putIp(this.ipsInTable[_i].id, this.ipsInTable[_i].json)
     .catch(err => {
       this.ipsInTable[_i].result = false;
       this.ipsInTable[_i].message = "Error";
       return Observable.throw(this.errorHandler(err));
     })
     .subscribe((data) => {
       _i++;
       publishIp(_i);           
        // Doing some stuff
     });
  }
}
publishIps(): void {
 console.log("Publishing Ips");

 publishIp(0);     
}
```

**Disclaimer:** I just typed this into stackoverflow.  You may have to fix some typos.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `mergeMap` with a throttle. The code would look something like this:

```
Observable
  // From takes an array and breaks each item into an individual event
  .from(arrayOfItems)
  // A mergeMap takes an event and converts it into a new observable
  // in this case -- a request. The second argument is how many items to 
  // allow in flight at once -- you can limit your network activity here.
  .mergeMap(item => saveItemObservable(item), requestLimit)
  // Will emit an event once all of the above requests have completed
  .toArray()
  // You will have an array of response results.
  .subscribe(arrayOfResults => { ... });
```

If you are using a newer version of RxJS it would look like this:

```
// You will need the correct imports:
// i.e import { from } from 'rxjs/observable/from';
// i.e. import { mergeMap, toArray } from 'rxjs/operators';
// From takes an array and breaks each item into an individual event
from(arrayOfItems).pipe(
     // A mergeMap takes an event and converts it into a new observable
     // in this case -- a request. The second argument is how many items to 
     // allow in flight at once -- you can limit your network activity here.
     mergeMap(item => saveItemObservable(item), requestLimit),
     // Will emit an event once all of the above requests have completed
     toArray()
  )
  // You will have an array of response results.
  .subscribe(arrayOfResults => { ... });
```

If you remove the `toArray` you will get an event in the subscription for each completed event.

Comment: You probably want `saveItemObservable(item)`?